# Accessing props function outside of the component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

React beginner here, i'm implementing zooming in/out functionality to my project using react-zoom-pan-pinch, i have my zooming buttons outside of 'TransformWrapper', all examples what i have seen have them inside 'TransformWrapper', so my question is how to have access to 'zoomIn','zoomOut','resetTransform'  outside of 'TransformWrapper'.

at the end i have tried it with useRef without success, is there a way ?

code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-zoom-pan-pinch-forked-j6yst?file=/src/index.js

code:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
`;
const Box = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: ${(props) => (props.backColor ? props.backColor : "blue")};
  margin: 5px;
`;
const Toolbox = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 60px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 2em;
  }
`;
function App() {
  const transformRef = useRef();

  const onClick = () => {
    alert("onClick : open popup");
  };
  const onContextMenu = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("onContextMenu : show info");
  };

  const renderBoxes = () => {
    let i;
    let arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      arr.push(
        <Box key={"b" + i} onClick={onClick} onContextMenu={onContextMenu} />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"r" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="red"
        />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"y" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="yellow"
        />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"g" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="gray"
        />
      );
    }
    return arr;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <TransformWrapper
        defaultScale={1}
        defaultPositionX={200}
        defaultPositionY={100}
        ref={transformRef}
      >
        {({
          zoomIn,
          zoomOut,
          resetTransform,
          positionX,
          positionY,
          ...rest
        }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Toolbox>
              <button onClick={zoomIn}>+</button>
              <button onClick={zoomOut}>-</button>
              <button onClick={resetTransform}>x</button>
            </Toolbox>
            <TransformComponent>
              <Container>{renderBoxes()}</Container>
            </TransformComponent>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </TransformWrapper>
      <Toolbox>
        <button onClick={() => transformRef?.current?.zoomIn()}>+</button>
      </Toolbox>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

i have tried with useRef as you can see in the code
<button onClick={() => transformRef?.current?.zoomIn()}>+< / button>
which doesnt work

i want to have this

```js
<Toolbox>
            <button onClick={zoomIn}>+</button>
            <button onClick={zoomOut}>-</button>
            <button onClick={resetTransform}>x</button>
          </Toolbox>
```

working outside of 'TransformWrapper' any idea ?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please stop deleting that comment and reposting it. It pings my notifications which is annoying. Downvotes are anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, mainly the problem was with codesandbox it uses react-zoom-pan-pinch 1.1.2 which is very old, upgrading it to 2.1.3 and using  a React ref on the TransformWrapper to access the handlers.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
`;
const Box = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: ${(props) => (props.backColor ? props.backColor : "blue")};
  margin: 5px;
`;
const Toolbox = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 60px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 2em;
  };
`
function App() {
  const transformComponentRef = useRef();
  const onClick = () => {
    alert("onClick : open popup");
  };
  const onContextMenu = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("onContextMenu : show info");
  };

  const renderBoxes = () => {
    let i;
    let arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      arr.push(
        <Box key={"b" + i} onClick={onClick} onContextMenu={onContextMenu} />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"r" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="red"
        />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"y" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="yellow"
        />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"g" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="gray"
        />
      );
    }
    return arr;
  };

  return (
    <div>
<button onClick={()=>transformComponentRef?.current?.zoomIn()}>+</button>
       
      <TransformWrapper
         ref={transformComponentRef}
        defaultScale={1}
        defaultPositionX={200}
        defaultPositionY={100}
       
      >
        {({
          zoomIn,
          zoomOut,
          resetTransform,
          positionX,
          positionY,
          ...rest
        }) => (
         
        
            <TransformComponent>
              <Container>{renderBoxes()}</Container>
            </TransformComponent>
       
        )}
      </TransformWrapper>
    
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```